# Universal Analytics Google - Pageviews

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm trying to record the hits for each author of a blog site.

```
ga('send', 'pageview'); (in the header with the ga code to track each page)
ga('send', 'pageview', { 'dimension1': 'William' }); (only on blog pages, I want to record the hits of each author)
```

Unfortunately, due to the templating of the site I can't just use `ga set` then send the pageview.

Will I get 2 hits for each page load, therefore showing incorrect data in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will get double page views which is incorrect. However Can you put your code in if else mode?

```
if(currentPage != 'blogpage') //put your conditions identifying if it's blog or not
{
     ga('send', 'pageview'); (in the header with the ga code to track each page)
}else
{
    ga('send', 'pageview', { 'dimension1': 'William' }); (only on blog pages, I want to record the hits of each author)
}
```